# Mysql current timestamp

Tags: mysql

I've mysql version:

```
C:\Users\mydir>mysql -V
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.4.11-MariaDB, for Win64 (AMD64), source revision 7c2c420b70b19cc02b5281...
```

and i try to update

```
MariaDB [mydb]> ALTER TABLE `mytable` CHANGE `created_at` `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
ERROR 1067 (42000): Invalid default value for 'deliverydate'
MariaDB [mydb]>
```

What it does mean?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the `CREATE TABLE` syntax of your table before changing it. Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query for SQL related questions.

Comment: Column and Error message don't match.